# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Error

Tags: android, sqlite

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEsusParticipants": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEsusParticipants(_idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, f_nameVARCHAR(255), m_nameVARCHAR(255));
```

my SQLite statement given error.i cant figure it out.any Help..

```
    private static final String DTABASE_NAME = "sport_unleash";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "susParticipants";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String F_NAME = "f_name";
    private static final String M_NAME = "m_name";
    private static final String CREATE_TALBE = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME +"("+ID +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + F_NAME + "VARCHAR(255), " + M_NAME+ "VARCHAR(255));";
```

Comment: Your SQL syntax is invalid, there is missing spaces for example. You should console log your CREATE_TABLE variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a space at the end of the `"CREATE TABLE"` string, and at the start of the `"("` string, as the table name doesn't have spaces in, and will be appended directly.

your string should look like:

```
    private static final String CREATE_TALBE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +" ("+ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + F_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + M_NAME+ " VARCHAR(255));";
```